# How to force a div to scale at 100% width of the current  windows Browser

Tags: html, css

I have a layout with a body tag. Body tag as css width for 960px;

I would like have a DIV inside the body tag, and I need this div be 100% width of the browser windows.

Unfortunately at the moment I'm not able to get the result because the internal div inherit from the body.

My question; How to force a div to scale at 100% width of the current Browser windows even if inside a body tag?.

PS. I try !important on width attribute but does not work

Thanks

Comment: Do you have sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant in your case. Instead of `width:960px` for the body use wrapper.

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    my content goes here
  </div>
  <div>
    my 100% width div goes here
  </div>
</body>

.wrapper { width:960px; margin:0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 2):

**I think your layout background is 100%, but your layout width is 960px. If it is your problem, then take 1 pixel vertical background top to bottom..**

Answer (score 0):

use jquery to get the width of the window : `$(window).width()` and update the width of the div using jquery with something like : `$("#theIDofDiv").css( "width", widthVar );`

note that this is not standard and in a proper format and the code hasnt been tested but in theory if body doesnt have `overflow:hidden`, you should be able to get the result you want